# Changing default folder structure of New Project in Unreal Engine?

Tags: unreal-4, unreal

I wonder is there a config option to change the default folder structure of a new project.

So for example when I create a new project there is already a folder for 'Blueprints', 'Maps', 'Audio' and 'FBX' sitting in my Content folder.

The reason I ask is it's usually the first thing i do after i create a new project.